# Module "version" in apache

Tags: apache2

I try to enable module version for apache2, with `a2enmod version` but return a error `ERROR: Module version does not exist!`

How do I install this module??

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

`mod_version` is statically compiled into Debian/Ubuntu's `apache2` packages. You can't install or enable it separately. It's directives will just work out of the box.

`apachectl -M` will show you the loaded modules.

Answer (score 0):

The `ERROR: Module version does not exist!` and `apachectl -M | grep version` outputs `version_module (static)` then its mean mod_version is statically compiled into apache2 package and works automatically.